# Cordova plugin admob Error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i'm add in my project this plugin  : 
**cordova-plugin-admob** 
when i'm build APK is give me this Error : [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP3dy.png)

> i'm update SDK android but is still same problem , i'm build whit CLI .